# Should doubt be epistemically justified?

Tags: epistemology, skepticism, uncertainty

If you doubt a claim X, should this very state of being in doubt be justified? How does one justify doubt in the first place? One can technically doubt anything except experience. But few would say that doubt in every area is justified. For example, is one justified in doubting that the earth is a sphere? Many would say no.

So if one does doubt that the earth is a sphere, would that mean that he has to somehow justify his doubt? How would this be done?

Comment: We might differentiate active doubt, *believing not*, from passive doubt, *not believing.* The latter is a sort of baseline/vacuum state (conceptually, anyway), for which justification seems less plausible to "require." Someone who is skeptical about all claims regarding the Earth's shape thus escapes the justification request; the Flat-Earther, who maintains an alternatively substantive position on said shape, does not escape it.

Comment: Offhand, anyway, that is a reasonable way to frame the issue. Kant claims in the *Religion* that some cognitive states are naturally/automatically nonempty, however, so if we find them emptied out within ourselves, this must be on account of an active deletion/suppression of the relevant content. But it might seem unlikely that we would have any positive default belief about the Earth's shape, for example.

Comment: @KristianBerry You could also say that the flat-earthers are not really doubters as much as asserters of their own theory (their very name is their asserted thesis). It's not active doubt as much as outright assertion of a thesis - which entails "actively doubting" competing theses. As such, they are subject to _onus probandi_. I would say that "active doubt" is just not genuine doubt.

Comment: @KristianBerry Also, it's not clear to me how far a discussion with a passive doubter would go: for any claim by person A, passive doubter B could only ever "doubt" it. As soon as B claims something, they leave their role as "passive doubter" to become owners of a given claim for which they have to provide support. Passive doubter B is free to passively doubt forever, but that means they are as good as not part of the debate, essentially.

Comment: @Frank, to the extent that doubt is not an attitude that undermines itself when carried "too far," it is probably in its passive state. However, if we say, "I doubt that..." we seem open to disambiguating our statement in either the active or passive direction. That unless, "I doubt that..." would preferably be analyzed as, "I lack belief that..." (there's a little infelicity in saying that we doubt the sentence, "Bloonagerians from Zorta Rorshuli eat panifronds for breakfast," for example, merely because we lack such a belief at all, usually).

Comment: @KristianBerry For your remark about Kant, is emptying really required? We could have a disposition and still examine it critically via rational doubt. We _should_ have methodical passive doubt in that sense.

Comment: @Frank, the example from Kant is the motive of duty. He says that practical reason is an inherently positive force, and would automatically produce its correlated motive in us if we did not somehow strive against such production. So when we find the motive of duty lacking within us, without the substantial presence of a motive of evil there either, though, he claims that we are finding out that we actively prevented the good motive from forming.

Comment: @KristianBerry Does he see that as a personal failure, or does he make room for social influences?

Comment: I'll have to leave off with this comment, since the site is doing its "move to chat" prompting. Kant actually does bring up social influences a lot in this connection; not only did reading Rousseau famously keep him from his "morning routine" (not even Hume brought on such a "startled" response), but then he does adapt the *amore de soi* vs. *amore propre* distinction to his social model of radical evil. And even in the *Religion* he further complicates things by saying that the motive of duty is not entirely deleted but is put "in the wrong slot" inside us.

Comment: >Should doubt be epistemically justified? I doubt that.

Comment: Why should someone who’s skeptical of all claims such as the earth being a sphere be epistemically justified to doubt?

Comment: @KristianBerry tagging

Comment: @Speakpigeon Yes, you do doubt it. But is that doubt justified? ; )

Comment: SEP's entry on [Epistemic Self Doubt](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemic-self-doubt/) has a lot of interesting things to say on this.

Comment: @JD "*But is that doubt justified?*" Do you doubt it?

Comment: "*He who doubts from what he sees will never believe, do what you please.*" - William Blake

Comment: "The best lack all conviction while the worst are full of passionate intensity" -Yeats

Answer (score 3):

The word "certainty," which is the English linguistic foil of the word "doubt," also happens to carry with it a sense of *specificity*, as when we say, "I met a certain cat on a certain road on a certain day." It is no surprise that Descartes would link clarity and certainty, then, since the [vagueness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vagueness/) of boundaries-by-generalization is then to be contrasted with the goal of identifying sharply demarcated particulars.

Yet then what is doubt, that it should be opposed to the other (though not wholly separate<sup>**?!**</sup>) main concept of [certainty](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/certainty/)? A similar, or equivalent, notion is of the suspension of belief or disbelief. We would not often speak of doubting things that we never even thought of before (I do not *doubt* that the Goddess of Algebra wears a top hat when performing for guests in the Gardens of Planet *X*), but this still leaves some room for speaking of doubt about assertions that we have yet to agree or disagree with in substance.

So, waiving complications regarding the diversity in negation theory, let us suppose there is (at least) *passive* doubt = *not believing*, and also *active* doubt = *believing not.* If our minds are not *tabula rasae*, then there might be cases where we are otherwise in the passive state modulo some beliefs, yet as a result of active suppression of our innate beliefs, then. [If we think that every action, even every mental action, is open to the question of justification](https://iep.utm.edu/virtue-epistemology/), then we could have passive doubts that are justifiable (or unjustifiable, as the case may be). On the other hand, a truly innate belief might be one that we are not able to suppress (or only suppress if we physically damage our brains); perhaps such things would be like Wittgenstein's "hinge propositions."

At any rate, it is active doubt in the direct sense that will call for justification by the by. One form of this justification might be [coherentism](https://iep.utm.edu/coherentism-in-epistemology/), which at least involves consistency on our part. If one has a high standard of evidence, then, the motive of consistency should lead us to doubt as many claims of a certain class as possible together instead of being a mere "contrarian" and going against "the official line." So someone who is willing to believe that the Earth has a specific shape only if they go out and explore every direction accessible to them (to find a flat edge or to wrap around a curved surface), and who doubts all assertions about said shape until they have done their own explorations, *and who resists believing in [testimony](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/testimony-episprob/) even when it is inconvenient for them to do so*, at least **seems** more justified in maintaining their state of doubt than the Flat Earther who combines the Bible and the conspiracy-theorist sector of the Internet to form their basis for attributing a lack of curvature to the planet's expanse. (I mean, this seeming can be qualified further by noting that other celestial objects apparently are curved, too, and these are objects visible "as a whole" from our current vantage, so unless we had reason to think that matter formed a square or a cube in the Earth's case and something more rounded in every other case that is visible to us, well...)

But note that many self-styled skeptics are only actively skeptical just so far as is dialectically convenient for them while they play word games with "normies." They will doubt the "official line" when it suits them (witness their propensity to cite official death rate statistics over the last year as "evidence" that COVID vaccines are causing a "depopulation event"). They will excuse this double-minded citation due to cynicism ("When elites and the mainstream media say positive things, don't trust them! But when those folks say bad things, you best believe they mean them...). So even if attempts at universal active doubt are intelligible and also justifiable, it is going to be hard to find concrete examples of when this state of affairs has actually obtained. (Note: these so-called skeptics don't seem to doubt, "There are elites," and, "There is a mainstream media," for example, all that much; I've challenged them on the latter, pointing to the diversity of media companies out there, to be met with a pseudopsychology "proof" that all these media companies can be clumped together as a monolith worthy of the word "the" prefacing them.)

Even Descartes, for instance, seems to have implicitly, or pragmatically, lacked doubt about the existence of the writing materials he must've used to put the *Meditations* down on paper.

---

<sup>**?!**</sup> It is easier to be certain about specific propositions than generalizations, perhaps; or at least, sometimes this tends to be the case. For a (universal, or at least broad) generalization runs more of a risk of being arrived at by an inductive fallacy, perhaps, than does a more one-off claim ("All (or at least most) ravens are like writing desks," vs., "This one raven that I'm looking at in bad lighting is like a writing desk," say).

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on the false assumption that it can be answered without considering specifics. It is rather like asking whether objects in France are bigger than objects in Germany- the answer depends on the objects and on what you mean by bigger.

Whether you need to justify a doubt depends on the circumstances. If you are an expert witness in court, doubting the evidence of a witness, you will certainly be expected to justify your doubt. If you doubt you will enjoy a holiday in Skegness, you are free to decide not to visit that delightful resort without having to justify your reservations.

Whether and how you might justify a doubt depends on the nature of the doubt. If you doubt your friend can lift 50kg with one hand, the doubt can be put to the test straightforwardly. If your doubt is about a matter of opinion, then you might not be able to justify it to the complete satisfaction of others.

The general recipe to justify a doubt is to reason logically from relevant evidence to the effect that the matter doubted is inconsistent with what a reasonable person would believe.

Answer (score 1):

We know from experience and observation (if we assume for a moment that our experiences and observations are reliable), that doubt is very often well-justified, in that it leads us to be skeptical of propositions which turn out to be false. This in turn often leads us to progress our knowledge, by fine-tuning it so that it becomes more aligned with reality (at least, *perceivable* reality).

To use - pedantically perhaps - your example of the Earth as a sphere... doubt about that very claim leads us to research and discover that the Earth is actually an imperfect sphere; an [oblate spheroid](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/oblate-spheroids) or [ellipsoid](https://www.unavco.org/education/resources/tutorials-and-handouts/tutorials/elevation-and-geoid.html#:%7E:text=The%20Earth%20is%20not%20a,out%20from%20side%20to%20side.).

So, if '[epistemic justification](https://press.rebus.community/intro-to-phil-epistemology/chapter/epistemic-justification/)' is described as something like:

> When you have epistemic justification for believing a proposition *p*, you thereby have a knowledge-contributing entitlement or right or warrant or good reason to believe that *p* is true...

... then our experience to date would suggest it is reasonable to claim that doubt is epistemically justified because:

> 'P: *We have good reason to believe that doubt often contributes to a more accurate understanding of whether or not a claim comports with reality*'.

Of course, even this statement is then subject to doubt, but this should cause little problem if it is subsequently investigated, for it should align with with the available evidence.

Comment: There are many cases in which people needlessly doubt things though. There are also cases of people with pathological doubt that doubt their memory. There’s many people who doubt the earth is a sphere, doubt the scientific enterprise, doubt we landed in the moon, etc. This isn’t a fringe part of the population. Are you suggesting they’re all epistemically justified in doubting?

Comment: @temptrt. The notion that doubt might often be needless would not counter the fact that doubt is epistemically justified. The reason for this is that we cannot know those instances (if any exist) in which doubt might not lead us to improve our knowledge/change our conclusions. Only by doubting do we avail ourselves of the possibility that we might be wrong, and in so doing commence the route towards greater knowledge

Comment: @SteveSaban That assumes that one feels certain of what’s justified and one feels uncertain when one is not. This doesn’t have to be the case. Similar to how you can fear something that is irrational, you can also doubt it. Doubt is just a psychological state

Comment: @Futilitarian I fail to see how that follows. If one finds out that their doubt was wrong, and say perhaps due to fear, then that would be an instance where the doubt was not epistemically justified. It would be based on a misunderstanding or something else that one would have had

Comment: @temptrt Uncertainty is not a psychological state. Uncertainty can be the cause of fear and anxiety but it's certainly not a psychology. Note that I'm deliberately substituting the word "doubt" with "uncertainty. Also, doubt isn't a belief it's uncertainty about a belief. So doubts can't "wrong" in the way a belief can be wrong.

Comment: @SteveSaban “uncertainty is not a psychological state.” That’s a pretty bold claim to make. Any evidence for this claim? In fact, every study done so far maps certain physiological feelings with uncertainty as far as I’m aware. And a doubt can’t be “wrong” since it’s a psychological state but it could be epistemically unjustified in the same way a person who doubts the earth is a sphere after seeing all the relevant evidence may be unjustified to do so. Your  feeling of certainty can’t be wrong either. You either feel it or you don’t.

Comment: @temptrt. Finding out one's "doubt was wrong" in no way means doubt wasn't epistemically justified. The reason for this is explicitly described in my answer (see from the first excerpt onwards). Doubts will regularly turn out be unwarranted (ie. it will eventuate there was no _need_ to worry), but the doubt itself was justified because it is only by doubting and investigating that we can find out how accurate we are. The epistemic justification lies not in whether we are right, but in the knowledge that doubt, in general, provides us the means of examining whether we are.

Comment: That can go both ways. For one can pathologically doubt and never reach a conclusion. After all, there is always a chance that you could be wrong on anything. Without doubting it, you’ll never find out. But there are likely cases where you’re not wrong and you’d be needlessly doubting and hence wasting your time

Comment: Agreed. But it's (kind of) like wearing a seatbelt. It's often unnecessary, but you're better off assuming you'll need it. As we can't reliably predict beforehand whether our doubt is warranted (whether we need the seatbelt), we're justified in doubting. If we don't doubt, we are doomed to persist with those delusions we fail to question (to suffer the car crashes of ignorance). The epistemic justification is that doubt provides us with a seatbelt against assumption. If the doubt turns out to be unjustified, we lose relatively little compared to what we would lose if we failed to doubt at all.

Comment: @Futilitarian By that logic, you should always be in doubt of everything, since almost every belief comes down to an assumption that is often asserted in a foundational way. This brings in the question of whether it’s epistemically justified to doubt everything since after all, it serves as a seatbelt. I would argue that as a psychological matter, it’s not justified, and by extension, epistemically not either. Remaining in doubt and uncertainty despite having thoroughly investigated something is a psychologically uncomfortable state like pain. You lose your quality of life. Thats what you lose

Comment: @temptrt. No. There is a clear difference in being _justified_ in doubt and in practicing doubt at every step. I believe I'm epistemically justified in doubting everything, but I don't live my life in doubt. If you asked me to reflect upon something I take for granted (such as whether wearing a seatbelt is a good idea), I can approach it with doubt in order to test the claim. I don't need to stop wearing the seatbelt.

Answer (score 0):

While I suspect that the Problem of Skepticism is more appealing to the philosophically inclined, it's a perfectly valid question of why shouldn't we just have faith and undermine the importance of doubt in critical thinking. While theology isn't my cup of tea (and you might also pursue an answer from theologians in addition to secular professional philosophers who are overwhelming [fallibilists (IEP)](https://iep.utm.edu/fallibil/)), religious epistemologies of fideists in the extreme may reject reason; since faith is a powerful tenet in these believes, it might be that argumentation to for and against doubt may be more developed.

I believe that doubt seems rather intuitive to anyone who professes a modicum of skepticism, and it's easy to see why. Moving from a naive realism even to a direct realism such as the position Searle outlines in his [*Seeing Things As They Are* (GB)](https://books.google.com/books?id=3jfvBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=seeing%20things%20as%20they%20are&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX48CHs6n8AhUVGTQIHdbkAWUQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=seeing%20things%20as%20they%20are&f=false) requires one to acknowledge certain experiences that underlie the need for justification of knowledge. A short, influential list cited repeatedly in philosophical works is illusion, confabulation, fallacy, hallucination, and falsity such as lying. And to boot, most people have experience with these in one forms or another (particularly if one sees dreams as a form of hallucination). I think these sources that reinforce the notion of doubt are relatively ubiquitous in works like Descartes, Hume, etc. and require little in the way of justification.

**I would suggest that certain types of doubt absolutely require epistemic justification, mainly the reliability of conscious experience in determining truth.** This can be seen in the canon vaguely as the struggle between rational and empirical philosophers, caricatured as a Descartes vs. Hume. The rationalists starting with Descartes have long held that conscious introspection is a reliable and thorough indicator of what happens between the ears; to see is to believe is a popular adage that moves in this direction of thinking. The philosophical exploration of [certainty (IEP)](https://iep.utm.edu/certainty/) is one activity that probes the opposite of doubt, which might best be conceived as an intuition. Modern cognitive science has shown beyond a shadow of doubt that human cognition is subject to bias and error and subconscious processes that betray any claims of the reliability of the rational, conscious mind, at least as Descartes envisioned it in his [*Meditations on First Philosophy* (GB)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Mv7dwAEACAAJ&dq=meditation%20on%20first%20philosophy&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4tvOrtan8AhVlGDQIHQOmCPYQ6AF6BAgFEAI).

How is it, when things so obvious to the conscious mind, that it can be so wrong? Why should I doubt the banana before me is not yellow? Why should I not believe in a creator when the world seems so complex that a designer seems the only reasonable explanation for things? Why should I give any credence to wave-particle duality when notions of substance and material are so good at explaining the universe? Why wouldn't my memory of what I saw 10 minutes ago be adequate as eyewitness testimony to support the conviction of someone accused of a crime? It is here that the justification of doubt occurs in fifty different ways. Each of those justifications, then, is a philosophical argument to explain why intuitions of certainty may be wrong, and in contemporary philosophy often rely on a [naturalized epistemology (IEP)](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-epis/) to bring the latest findings of neurology, criminology, or sociology to bear on thinking.

Answer (score 0):

One cent.

Doubting something, is a also a kind of assertion, eg that "this is doubtful".

Refusing to justify an assertion based on something (even on something as simple as something self-evident), means one is accepting that some assertions need no justification at all. But if that is the case, then why ask for (further) justification for the original statement? One then is bound to accept justification is not necessary for (at least some) assertions.

This results in using double standards and asking for special *epistemological* treatment regarding statements and assertions.

A justified doubt/challenge promotes understanding and leads to better and better arguments for/against some assertion. In other words, it promotes knowledge. An unjustified doubt does not promote knowledge. Paraphrasing a known maxim: "*What is claimed without justification, can be dismissed without justification*".

On top of that, if *reality* is such that some assertions are simply given (ie they are foundational) or have been justified to the maximum degree, then the doubter, by asking for (further) justification, without being able to justify the need for that (ie without being able to argue/show the assertion is not foundational or not adequately justified), makes an epistemological error.

PS: The justification for a doubt/challenge, being just another statement/assertion, is  not different than justifying any other statement.