# Is persistent uncertainty irrational?

Tags: uncertainty, doubt

Doubt, uncertainty, and questioning things are considered hallmarks in philosophy. Not being certain in a belief is considered a virtue due to how often we are mistaken.

But philosophy is also associated with finding out the truth about things. However, being uncertain implies having a probabilistic form of belief that doesn’t seem to exist in reality for many things. For example, ghosts are either real or not. The earth is either a sphere or not. With these kinds of things, reality is binary. When it comes to matters of existence, there are no grey areas. As such, why is it sensible to leave even a bit of a doubt in your beliefs about these matters?

If a rational belief is one that amounts to having a belief that is both justified and is true, how can it be rational to even say “I think the earth is most likely a sphere but I could be wrong.”

If the earth is a sphere, then wouldn’t you ultimately be wrong for even thinking that it’s a possibility that the earth isn’t a sphere? If it’s not a sphere, you would also be wrong.

Being uncertain seems to make your belief wrong either way. Being certain atleast seems to make your belief correct if you turn out to be right. Why is the former then considered more rational?

Comment: This is why the Halting Problem

Comment: It might help if you explain what was useful/not useful from your previous question, [Should doubt be epistemically justified?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95681/should-doubt-be-epistemically-justified). There seems to be substantial cross-over.

Comment: That question is more about whether doubt as a state of mind NEEDS to be justified. This question is more about whether or not it is ever justified to leave room for doubt in any belief.

Comment: If one tries to calculate the gravity of earth using Gauss's law the math is simplified by the assumption that the geometry of earth is a perfect sphere and the matter in the sphere has uniform density. Gravity would be uniform in this model. In reality gravity is not uniform everywhere surrounding the earth due to imperfections in the assumptions of spherical geometry and uniform density. Based on rational efforts like this should we doubt or be certain of the statement that the earth is a sphere? Often a proposition is more true or false in some context. Doubt must arise to test any "truth".

Comment: "When all candles be out, all cats be grey" - proverb

Comment: Being in doubt is not holding a belief. One can't be wrong about a position they don't hold, so your idea that being in doubt is being wrong all the time could actually be construed as the exact opposite (as explained in an answer below). Problem is, when in doubt one can't be right either. I think your confusion arises from sticking to the idealist model that one has to be either right or wrong about something when in reality "I don't know" or "I am kinda but not quite sure" are the kind of position most people hold about most facts.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: No. Scientific Method considers all truths discovered to be tentative, and only as certain as their evidence - meaning there is no space in science for total certainty about anything, we just don't have evidence of ghosts plus reasons to relate them to cognitive biases, and psychology like guilt or lack of closure. And science is considered a rational mode of investigation.

Proof in mathematics can demonstrate a consequence with certainty - but, only *once definitions, axioms and abstractions are accepted* as certain.

Hume identified the [Problem of Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_induction): however reliable the past has been as a guide, the universe has the last word on future regularities or lack if them.

You might like this answer on how we can reconcile mathematical universality, with the lack of certainties in science: [The Unreasonable Ineffectiveness of Mathematics in most sciences](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92058/the-unreasonable-ineffectiveness-of-mathematics-in-most-sciences/92064#92064)

> there are no grey areas

What about actual areas, where everything is grey? And, granted it's metaphorical sense, what about [challenges to the law-of-the-excluded-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle#cite_note-4)? For instance in the Buddhist 'four cornered' logic of the catuskoti, it can be recognised that multiple layers of thinking about things can be valid, yet give incompatible or irreconcilable results. See eg:
[The logic of Buddhist philosophy goes beyond simple truth](https://aeon.co/essays/the-logic-of-buddhist-philosophy-goes-beyond-simple-truth).

Humility about our knowledge, and recognising what basis we have drawn our conclusions from is part of the conclusiins, has been crucial to moving away from endless religious and ideological wars. Other than math, only religious zealotry imbues people with a sense of certainty, and no I don't think that is better than recognising you have been or could be wrong.

Being wrong is part of the learning process, fear of being wrong inhibits learning, and creativity.

Comment: Science considers all knowledge discovered to be tentative, but it's also important to note that *science is the best we've got*. If anyone wants to criticise science for this and claim they have complete certainty, to justify this, they would need to demonstrate that their methodology for discovering truth is demonstrably absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the justification is not often infallible, for example, in the case of justifying why earth is a sphere, empirical evidence is used. However even the empirical evidence can be questioned, like what if the earth is some other shape, and we are being deceived somehow, or other alternate possible explanations of what else might be happening.

Thus, keeping doubt in such claims is more rational because you acknowledge that you don't have an infallible justification, and that your claims could change based on new information/evidence, and also that giving an infallible justification is not possible. Although the earth might actually be a sphere, but we cannot be certain that it is, due to the same reasons as before. Without doubt, you are just saying that your justification is enough and infallible, which isn't true or rational.

Also, the statement "I think the earth is most likely a sphere but I could be wrong." is equivalent to saying "I think the earth is a sphere or I might be wrong", the below truth table makes it clear enough then on what is more rational.

[image]

Comment: The second row, in my eyes, should show false in both columns. When you doubt something, you are acknowledging the possibility that you are wrong. But if the earth is a sphere, you were wrong about considering that even as a possibility thus wrong for doubting. If a possibility doesn’t exist, in what way were you correct?

Comment: @thinkingman The doubting is basically just saying the disjunction "The earth is a sphere or it is not", where if the earth is actually a sphere, then the whole doubting statement is true as its first part is true, and if the earth is not actually a sphere, then the whole doubting statement is true again as its second part "it is not" is true.

Comment: That’s just a tautology that everyone, including the person who firmly believes the earth is a sphere, recognizes. Saying that “Ghosts either exist or not” is not a belief. A belief which you leave room for doubt such as “I believe in ghosts but could be wrong” is not equivalent to the former. The latter is a mental state and is a claim that being wrong is an actual possibility in reality. The former doesn’t depend on your mental state and is a logical necessity hence a tautology

Comment: @thinkingman So isn't the former statement “Ghosts either exist or not” also saying the same thing that maybe ghosts don't exists, i.e being an actual possibility in reality.

Comment: It is a false claim the earth is a sphere. It's an [oblate spheroid](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroid). ; )

Comment: @JD Considering earth a sphere is just *ad argumentandum* although it being a oblate spheroid actually shows how having a doubt is rational.

Comment: I know. Thus, an upvote. :D

Comment: Thank you @JD :D

Comment: @SiddharthChakravarty The greater lesson is that models (the earth is a flat plane) can be seen as progressing from obvious to requiring more clever reasoning (the earth is a sphere) into even more clever and technical arguments (the earth is an oblate spheroid). Thus, to be persistently uncertain, at least in the context of moving from intuitive to rational thinking developing ever more adequate models is very rational. Where would the sciences be if they didn't encourage persistent uncertainty?!? :D

Comment: @JD Agreed ,without doubt we wouldn't have even gone past the theory of earth being flat, otherwise we would just be dogmatic and not rational.

Comment: No because one is not a state of mind and the other is a belief hence a state of mind @SiddharthChakravarty. A person cannot believe in two contradictory things at once. Perhaps you can suspend belief entirely but most of the time you when people say “I believe ghosts don’t exist but I might be wrong” they don’t mean it in that sense

Comment: @thinkingman If I say "I believe ghosts don’t exist but I might be wrong” does it mean that "I think ghosts don't exist for sure", no, right? Similarly it won't mean that "I think ghosts exist for sure". That just means you are a bit inclined towards one side but not completely towards it,  which means it is still same as the disjunction statement, because you would only be wrong if you were completely inclined towards a side, even though you didn't have any infallible justification for your claim, and not acknowledging that there is place for doubt.

Comment: @thinkingman A belief is a state of mind. I'm not sure why you believe they are different. It's a sophisticated mind that can keep two contradictory notions at the same time to paraphrase G.K. Chesterton.

Answer (score 3):

In the tradition of western Philosophy, this goes back to the Socratic paradox "I know that I know nothing" as recounted by Plato. Given human ability to perceive reality (including perception of their own limits) precisely, it is rational to remain doubtful.

> If the earth is a sphere, then wouldn’t you ultimately be wrong for even thinking that it’s a possibility that the earth isn’t a sphere?

It depends. There is a difference between reasonable doubt and unreasonable doubt, which is driven by the knowledge you have and the alternative you conceive, and what is at stake.

As a person who never went to school and never travelled, a belief that earth may rather be a small disc is not unreasonable, even if wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is something to be said for being aware of the limits of rationalisation.  Both Buddha and Kant have a similar line in this.  Buddha with the undeclared or indeterminate (avyākata) questions.

[Avyākṛta : Ten indeterminate questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_unanswerable_questions#Avy%C4%81k%E1%B9%9Bta) e.g. [Cula-Malunkyovada Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.063.than.html)

> 'The cosmos is eternal,' ... 'The cosmos is not eternal,' ... are
> undeclared by me.   And why are they undeclared by me? Because they
> are not connected with the goal... They do not lead to disenchantment,
> dispassion, cessation, calming, direct knowledge, self-awakening,
> Unbinding.

And [Kant's mathematical antinomies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kant%27s_antinomies#The_mathematical_antinomies) : of space and time.

> - Thesis: The world has a beginning in time, and is also limited as
>   regards space.
> - Anti-thesis: The world has no beginning, and no limits
>   in space; it is infinite as regards both time and space.

of which the SEP says in [4.1 The Mathematical Antinomies](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-metaphysics/#MatAnt)

> In each of these antinomial conflicts, reason finds itself at an
> impasse. Satisfying the demands placed by our rational capacity to
> think beyond experience, the thesis arguments offer what appears to be
> a satisfying resting-place for explanation. ... In each of these
> cases, the conflicts are resolved by demonstrating that the
> conclusions drawn on both sides are false.
>
> How does Kant demonstrate this? ... for example, we may want to know,
> as in the first antinomy, whether the world is finite or infinite. We
> can seek to show that it is finite by demonstrating the impossibility
> of its infinitude. Alternatively, we may demonstrate the infinitude of
> the world by showing that it is impossible that it is finite. This is
> exactly what the thesis and antithesis arguments purport to do,
> respectively.

Kant goes on to establish limits to rationalisation in his *Critique of Pure Reason*.  So a couple of precedents there for living with uncertainty.